# How to rotate imageview without changing its position in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, rotation

I can rotate the image view but it is changing its position my question is How to rotate image view without changing its position. thank you for your response. Very much appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: I had this same issue with a project I'm currently working on. I'm rotating three UIImageView, so I ended up putting them all in a containing UIView which fixed the problem. (The images are all the same size)

Answer (score 0):

By default, view's rotate about their center points, which means that they don't move when rotated. However, if you're using autolayout, then you must set the horizontal and vertical constraints properly.  Specifically, the constraints should be `Center X alignment` and `Center Y alignment`.  If instead, you have `Top space...` and `Leading space...` constraints, then the view will probably move when rotated.